# Java - Put Request

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to perform a `"PUT"` but nothing happens, i don't catch any exception either.

Here is what I've tried:

```
String destinationUrl = 'http://stash.myDomain.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/myProj/permissions/users?name=myUser&permission=PROJECT_WRITE';

URL url = null;
try {
    url = new URL(destinationUrl)
} catch (MalformedURLException exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

try {
    String userpass = STASH_USERNAME + ":" + STASH_PASSWORD;
    String basicAuth =  "Basic " + converter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes());
    httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth)
    //httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream());
    dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Hello");
} catch (IOException excepption) {
    excepption.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (dataOutputStream != null) {
        try {
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if (httpURLConnection != null) {
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Any idea what should i do ?

Comment: How do you check if anything happens? Why don't you try consuming the connection input stream and see if there is some status code?

Comment: While you are at it, think about wrapping the stream with BuferedOutputStream, since the DataOutputStream is not buffered.

Comment: Unless this is a restricted environment, use a higher-level abstraction for HTTP.

Comment: Which one ? BTW, the URLConnection which is the super class doesn't allow me to set the type of the request (E.G PUT/POST, etc.)

Comment: I've added those lines:
`int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
 println (responseCode);` 
and i'm getting 204 which is weird. When i'm running a simple CURL Command it's working fine.
`curl -u user:password -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT "http://stash.mydomain.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/someProj/permissions/users?name=someUser&permission=PROJECT_WRITE" `

Comment: I think it is a API thing, not about your code. One of the things I see is that you are using someProj in the comment but myProj in the snippet. I do not know if there is any difference and what does that mean, just saying. A 204 response means that the server is doing something, but your call is "wrong".

Comment: The thing is that I'm doing the same as call as i did with the `CURL`